# Web.Config strange <customErrors> section?

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I was going through an ASP.Net web forms tutorial [here:](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-45/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/aspnet-error-handling) on asp.net website. This tutorial contains a section for custom errors, which is a bit strange to me.

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="ErrorPage.aspx?handler=customErrors%20section%20-%20Web.config">
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="ErrorPage.aspx?msg=404&amp;handler=customErrors%20section%20-%20Web.config" />
</customErrors>
```

**Question:** Can someone explain the query string parameter `handler=customErrors%20section%20-%20Web.config"` in **defaultRedirect** & **redirect**?

Does this syntax have a special meaning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `%20` are just URL encoded spaces. It's sending a human-readable name of what redirected to the error handler page in the query string.